# double free or corruption (out) error at the end of ROS2 C++ subscriber callback function when used with PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, ros2, subscriber

System used: ROS2 foxy on Ubuntu 20.04 with PCL 1.10 installed on amd64 architecture.

I have created a C++ subscriber for ROS2 topic `velodyne_points` of the message type `sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2`. Since, this is ROS2 message and PCL can't handle it. So, I first convert it to something (`pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud;`) which PCL can understand using `pcl_conversions::toPCL(*msg, cloud);` where msg is the pointer to ROS message and cloud contains the converted PCL data. Then, I want to apply PCL's `voxelGrid` functionality. Since `voxelGrid.setInputCloud(cloudPtr);` takes the argument as a pointer(**the const boost shared pointer to a PointCloud message**), I create one which points to PCL "cloud" using `pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloudPtr (&cloud);`, process it further and save the result in a memory location pointed by `cloud_filtered`. But as soon as program reaches the end of this subscriber callback function, it gives an error `double free or corruption (out)` on the terminal and execution stops (No error in compilation, only in execution).

I tried to understand this error but I am not trying to free some pointer explicitly which is already free. This issue happens because of the line `pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloudPtr (&cloud);` because when I tried commenting this line and the voxelization steps, execution worked well. But I need to do voxelization and some more steps after it is done (ground plane segmentation, clustering etc.).

I am trying to build ROS2 package and run the executable using this command : `clear && colcon build --packages-select custom_nav_stack_pkg --symlink-install && source install/local_setup.bash && ros2 run custom_nav_stack_pkg cpp_executable` which looks fine to me.

Here is the code.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp"
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/conversions.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    MinimalSubscriber()    //Constructor which has the same name as that of class followed by a parentheses. A constructor in C++ is a special method that is automatically called when an object of a class is created. 
    : Node("minimal_subscriber")
    {
      subscription_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>
      ("velodyne_points", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

  private:
    void topic_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr msg) const
    {
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I received the message , height is: '%d'", msg->height); //
      pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud;
      pcl_conversions::toPCL(*msg, cloud);

      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I received the PCL message , height is: '%d'", cloud.height);
     
      std::cerr << "PointCloud before filtering: " << cloud.width * cloud.height 
             << " data points (" << pcl::getFieldsList (cloud) << ")." << std::endl;

      
      // Declaring pointer for the PCL "cloud" 
      pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloudPtr (&cloud);

      // define a new container for the data
      pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2 ());

      // define a voxelgrid
      pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> voxelGrid;
      // set input to cloud
      voxelGrid.setInputCloud(cloudPtr);
      // set the leaf size (x, y, z)
      voxelGrid.setLeafSize(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
      // apply the filter to dereferenced cloudVoxel
      voxelGrid.filter(*cloud_filtered);   

      std::cerr << "PointCloud after filtering: " << cloud_filtered->width * cloud_filtered->height 
       << " data points (" << pcl::getFieldsList (*cloud_filtered) << ")." << std::endl;

      std::cin.ignore();
    }
    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr subscription_;

};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Inside main function now" << std::endl;
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

Running it gives me below output.

```
Starting >>> custom_nav_stack_pkg
Finished <<< custom_nav_stack_pkg [16.4s]                       

Summary: 1 package finished [16.7s]
Inside main function now
[INFO] [1664396894.528685765] [minimal_subscriber]: I received the message , height is: '1'
[INFO] [1664396894.528876950] [minimal_subscriber]: I received the PCL message , height is: '1'
PointCloud before filtering: 15000 data points (x y z intensity ring time).
PointCloud after filtering: 5937 data points (x y z intensity ring time).

double free or corruption (out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloudPtr (&cloud);` is the problem: the variable `cloud` (declared as `pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud;`) is managed by the stack and automatically destroyed/freed at the end of the function. `pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr` is a `shared_ptr` (a `boost::shared_ptr` in older PCL versions and `std::shared_ptr` in newer PCL versions, but that makes no difference here). The shared pointer will manage the object it points to and will destroy/free it when no longer needed, which is the case at the end of the function. So `cloud` is destroyed/freed twice.

`pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloudPtr (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2 ());` is the right way to use the shared pointer. To avoid copy operations, I would recommend to create `cloudPtr` at the beginning of the function, don't use the stack-managed `pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud;` at all, and instead use `*cloudPtr` in `pcl_conversions::toPCL` and everywhere else where you would use `cloud`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped in understanding the issue and fixing it as well. By the way, I asked this question on ROS answers too and a helping hand over there did the same fix as well. I can't put the whole code over here because of comment length limitation but here is the link to the question who might need it: [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/407071/double-free-or-corruption-out-error-with-pcl/)